# How click on options from floating action button?

Tags: android, selenium, automated-tests, appium, floating-action-button

I'm automating an app with Selenium and Appium and this app has an floating action button with some options like follow image. The main button (that opens the options) is possible to click, but I can't click on the options, because there isn't specification for this elements on the UI Automator viewer. Can you help me please? How can I automating the click on this buttons?
The floating action button has animation and has attributes defined in xml archive, but these attributes aren't showed in UI Automator viewer.

### Sample

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can click by using the image ID, or by adding the ID in the list and clicking with the selected index.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to perform actions on similar floating buttons. These elements are visible in UiAutomator, below is the screen shot :

[image: Click here to see the screen shot]

Also, I update your android SDK once, because UiAutomator works with available apis on your local Machine.

**I suggest you to update SDK and try to capture the elements on device with OS version 6.0+ (which means Marshmallow or higher version).** I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers! The buttons really wasn't able in UIAutomator view, so I use the coordinates in this case.